# Where can you get access to PM related on-line resources?

Tags: education, learning, books

This is posted with intention of making it a community wiki

Please provide organisations that provide on-line trainings, resources, books etc related to project management. Please also write if the access is free, and if not- how much it costs.

### **Free resources**

- From [Project Management Institue](http://www.pmi.org/)
- - [Project Management Proffesional Credential Handbook](http://www.pmi.org/en/Certification/~/media/PDF/Certifications/pdc_pmphandbook.ashx)
- [ProjectManagement.com](http://www.projectmanagement.com/): Free whitepapers and articles
- [Business Balls](http://www.businessballs.com/project.htm): "free ethical learning and development resource for people and organizations"
- [Free Management Library](http://managementhelp.org/): "The Library provides free, easy-to-access, online articles to develop yourself, other individuals, groups and organizations"
- [American Management Association](http://www.amanet.org/): both free and non-free content
- [IT Metrics & Productivity Institute](http://www.itmpi.org/webinars/): free PMI accredited webinars

**Agile**

- [Control Chaos](http://www.controlchaos.com/): Scrum home page
- [Extreme Programming: A gentle introduction](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/): XP Home Page
- [Links to various resources at TargetProcess's site](http://www.targetprocess.com/LearnAgile/AgileResources.aspx)
- [Agile Coaching Resources](http://www.agilexp.com/agile-resources.php)

**Quality Management**

- [iSixSigma](http://www.isixsigma.com/): blogs and articles

### **Free but limited access**

- [Defense Acquisition University](http://www.dau.mil/default.aspx): Topics mostly related to US Departament od Defense. Requires [CAC](http://www.cac.mil/)

### **Paid access resources**

- [Project Management Institue](http://www.pmi.org/). They have some free resources, but for the most part you need to pay their membership that goes for about $100/year
- [American Management Association](http://www.amanet.org/): both free and non-free content
- [Association for Computing Machinery](http://www.acm.org/) : paid membership (depending on what country you're from it can be as low as $20/year) grants you full access to Safari Books and Books 24x7 as well as several on-line courses. See [ACM Learning Center](http://learning.acm.org/).

**Commercial training offerrings**

- [PMCentersUSA](http://www.pmcentersusa.com/)

Comment: As per site scope changes, this question wouldn't be on-topic or in scope anymore. See [meta] to follow the conversations.

Answer (score 6):

- [Project Management Institute](http://www.pmi.org). As Geo stated before. There are some free resources, but membership goes for about $100/year.
- [PMI handbook](http://www.pmi.org/en/Certification/~/media/PDF/Certifications/pdc_pmphandbook.ashx), free.
- [Project Managment](http://www.projectmanagement.com/), free.
- [Business Balls](http://www.businessballs.com/project.htm), free.
- [Free Management Library](http://managementhelp.org/), free.
- [Agile Project Management for IT Projects](http://www.niwotridge.com/PDFs/PM%20Chapter%20%28short%20no%20email%29%20Update%202.pdf), free (.pdf file)
- [Target Process](http://www.targetprocess.com), there are some resource free, but there are TargetProcess On-Site ($249 per user) and TargetProcess On-Demand ($25 per user)
- Also see this:[Management books
  *by Joel Spolsky*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/06/29.html).

Answer (score 3):

- This is a given, [Project Management Institue](http://www.pmi.org/). They have some free resources, but for the most part you need to pay their membership. The membership goes for about $100/year
- The PMI Chapter near your own city

I will continue adding later.

Answer (score 1):

Free PM resources that I have used:

1. [Defense Acquisition University](http://www.dau.mil/) - free, but probably only useful to people doing work for the US DoD, but it has a wealth of PM information for those who can get in.  You'll need a [CAC](http://www.cac.mil/).
2. [Control Chaos](http://www.controlchaos.com/) - the Scrum home page. Free.
3. [Extreme Programming: A Gentle Introduction](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/). The XP Home page. Free.
4. [iSixSigma Top Rated Articles](http://www.isixsigma.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&Itemid=156)
5. [American Management Association](http://www.amanet.org) - has lots of free and non-free resources. Haven't used it a ton, but unlike many sites, they don't hide their free resources behind a lot of clutter.  The site is well organized and it's easy to find things.

Free and non-Free Resources I have not used, or used only very occasionally:

1. http://www.pmcentersusa.com/ - mostly non-free
2. [Agile Coaching Resources](http://www.agilexp.com/agile-resources.php)
3. http://www.itmpi.org/webinars/ - free