# Project Management Training/Certificates

Tags: career, skills, education, training, certification

Which Project Management trainings or certificates would you recommend to take if you do not have any PM background/experience.

I can see some questions for Templates, Software, etc... but I would be really interested on references to training for people that are new to this area.

Comment: What industry are you working in? Is it software development or something else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [shopping question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: This question is both too broad and too opinion-based. While some judicious editing might make it on-topic, the scope would have to be much more targeted to avoid making it an opinion poll, and the specificity might then make it to unique to have lasting value. These are just some of the reasons that career advice is considered off-topic per our help center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would definitely recommend you to take the **[PRINCE2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRINCE2) Foundation and Practitioner** training.

With this training you will gain solid knowledge about Project Management and everything that surrounding a project regardless of your background (IT, Marketing, etc...)

Answer (score 5):

I would also support Prince 2 Practitioner, for the reasons provided by the earlier responses. One word of caution, however: it teaches you the fundamentals, but it is not realistic to expect that a week's training course can take someone from project naivety to project expert. The title "practitioner" is a bit of a misnomer on that basis! - but it is a great way to start.

I also reckon that the official OGC course manual (Managing successful projects with PRINCE2) is a valuable reference source, especially Appendix A, which provides product description outlines for all of the products that you need. (It is also a very helpful resource to use during the exam!)

If sitting the exam, you will be able to take your manual in with you and refer to anything that is written (but not stapled or otherwise inserted) into the book.

Good luck if you go down this route.

Answer (score 5):

My first contact with Project Management was on a [Junior Enterprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junior_enterprise) when I was asked to write a Project Plan following a template.

The Project Plan was not critical, so I had time to work and learn on it adding the feedback received from my colleagues.

I had the opportunity to follow the project execution with my colleagues. I learned a lot with that.

So, buildup a theoretic knowledge base and consider having a coach to give you some practical experience. This will improve your PM skills. **Look at [this](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/339/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-gain-experience-that-can-lead-to-working-in-a-p) related question.**

Consider improving your personal skills. Identify which personal skill you lack the most and improve it. Read [this](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/493/105) and [this](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/77/105) questions to find the most revelant personal skills for a PM.

Use [this](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/87/105) question as a reference to PM on-line resource.

Take some time reading related blogs like:

- http://blog.brodzinski.com/
- http://www.joelonsoftware.com/ (I like very much [The Identity Management Method](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/10.html) article)
- http://www.vertabase.com/blog/

Remember: [PMSE](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) itself is also a place to be if you want to learn PM stuff.

**Good luck**

Answer (score 3):

I second the PRINCE2 Practitioner certification as it gives you a good overview of a general project management methodology. If you are a software development focused project manager a ScrumMaster certification would be useful as this is becoming more and more common place as a software development methodology.

I have a few colleagues who have done the PMP training and they rated it very highly.

Answer (score 3):

[Microsoft Project certification](http://www.microsoft.com/project/en/us/find-training.aspx)/training. This helps understand step-by-step features and concepts which are needed to plan and manage projects effectively. You will learn how to think and organize your projects details, plan a schedule, sequence tasks, produce a baseline, assign resources and costs, and revise your project plan.

Comment: Hi Denis, I like your suggestion, I think the more tools you can handle the better. However, I am not sure about how this certificate can support new PMs. Would you recommend this training in combination to something else?

Answer (score 1):

you can find online [Project Management Training](http://skillforge.com/courses/project-management/) and [Microsoft Project Training](http://skillforge.com/courses/category/project-management/microsoft-project-and-project-server-training) at several online sites. Most offer introductory Project Management theory classes as well as training in software tools for project management. Some sites are:

- www.skillforge.com
- www.iil.com
- www.learnquest.com